# Is there any way to get correct degrees of freedom in gls, matching those of paired t-test?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, degrees-of-freedom, generalized-least-squares

I have the following data:

```
data <- structure(list(sample = 1:8, methodx = c(0.52, 0.5, 0.48, 0.4, 
0.36, 0.3, 0.28, 0.28), methody = c(0.53, 0.51, 0.48, 0.41, 0.36, 
0.32, 0.3, 0.29)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

and its long form:

```
d_long <- structure(list(sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), method = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("methody", 
"methodx"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.52, 0.5, 0.48, 0.4, 
0.36, 0.3, 0.28, 0.28, 0.53, 0.51, 0.48, 0.41, 0.36, 0.32, 0.3, 
0.29)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

The GLS with compound symmetry should match paired t-test ideally.
It does with the test statistics.
It does not with the degrees of freedom, completely ignoring there are 2 observations per sample (paired data).

Is there any way to "tell" GLS to make it right?

```
> t.test(data$methodx, data$methody, paired = T) 

    Paired t-test

data:  data$methodx and data$methody
t = -3.7417, df = 7, p-value = 0.007247
...
```

and gls()  (denom. df = 14, not 7!)

```
> anova(gls(value ~ method,  correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~1|sample), d_long))
Denom. DF: 14 
            numDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1 128.6804  <.0001
method          1  14.0000  0.0022
```

I want to use gls for modelling a longitudinal data, as it allows me to use various correlation structures, but if it fails at finding df in the simplest example, I cannot use that.

Is there any work around?

I do not want to use mixed models, as random intercept model IS NOT equivalent to compound symmetry, I often get negative correlations, and don't want them to be made 0 in lme4...

EDIT:
lme4 handled it correctly, both DF and p-value agree with paired t-test:

```
> anova(lmer(value ~ method + (1|sample), d_long), ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
       Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
method 0.0004  0.0004     1     7      14 0.007247 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

EDIT: it seems that GLS ignores the "clustering" and only models the covariance among samples, leaving the DF as they are...

Answer (score 0):

A paired t-test is a one-sample t-test on the differences between individuals in groups. In this sense, you can use gls to match the output of t.test by typing:

```
summary(gls(methodx - methody ~ 1, data = data))
...
Coefficients:
            Value   Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept) -0.01 0.002672612 -3.741657  0.0072
...
```

You can also use `lme` from the same package to match the results from `lme4`.

```
summary(lme(value ~ method, random = ~ 1 | sample, data = d_long))
...
Fixed effects: value ~ method 
              Value  Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)    0.40 0.03484660  7 11.478881  0.0000
methodmethodx -0.01 0.00267261  7 -3.741657  0.0072
...
```

Your first attempt at using gls was more like a (variance corrected) two-sample t-test than a paired test, which is why the df was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response! Let me ask about one thing. If I want, in future, to run a longitudinal model, like in SAS with REPEAT statement (no random effects, just covariance structure), I will likely face the same problem with DF, because the GLS will not care about the time points. This is what is called "fake data replication" - using the all available DFs, while these are repeated for the same subjects. Here you were able to "force" it do it. But if I have 3 time points, like t0...t3? Let's say I'd like to run value ~ treatment * time + baseline model with GLS.

Comment: Or even simpler - only time. lme4 will guess, that the DF should be split into these times, and GLS will use everything available, giving invalid p-values. My example here was to find a way to tell gls() to use df=7, not 14. You achieved that with switching to differences. lme4 didn't need that. What if if there are more time points? The idea is: to mimic SAS in running  a longitudinal analysis with defined (say, compound symmetry) analysis, not employing random effects, instead focusing on the residual covariance, as SAS does. The DFs seem to be the only problem here. lme4 was able to handle.

Comment: Niether lme4 nor gls are guessing df in these simple balanced models. the lme4 model is a random effects models, and the gls model is a one-sample t-test. I'm not sure what SAS does (have not used it in years), so I regret I can't be helpful . If this is a new question, I recommend opening a new thread. In the thread, try to write out the likelihood you want to estimate and we can help you fit the model in R.

Comment: Yes, I posted it a second ago. Thank you very much for your help and your time! I just thought that gls will be able to do the same lme does but just with a slightly different formulation (random effects structure vs. covariance structure), and expected, that if lme can infer the proper DF=7 from the model, gls will do the same. I was wrong, but maybe others will show me a way or correct my expectations :) Thanks a lot!