# Unstructured model vs random slope model for repeated measures based on R functions lmer, lme and gls

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, generalized-least-squares

Here is the dataset for repeated measures:

```
library(lme4)
library(nlme)

d=read.delim("http://dnett.github.io/S510/RepeatedMeasures.txt")
d$Program = factor(d$Program)
d$Subj = factor(d$Subj)
d$Timef = factor(d$Time)
```

I have built an unstructured model using gls function and I am trying to reproduce the results using a random slope (or random slope + intercept) model fitted by R functions lmer or lme. Here is the code and output:

gls function:

```
> d.gls <- gls(Strength ~ Program * Timef, data = d,
+     correlation = corSymm(form =~ 1 | Subj),
+     weight = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Timef))
> getVarCov(d.gls)
Marginal variance covariance matrix
       [,1]   [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]
[1,] 8.7801 8.7571  8.9656  8.1984  8.6781  8.2203  8.4169
[2,] 8.7571 9.4730  9.4631  8.5686  9.2012  8.7307  8.6875
[3,] 8.9656 9.4631 10.7080  9.9266 10.6660 10.0700 10.2140
[4,] 8.1984 8.5686  9.9266 10.0770 10.6000  9.8987 10.0430
[5,] 8.6781 9.2012 10.6660 10.6000 12.0950 11.3440 11.3640
[6,] 8.2203 8.7307 10.0700  9.8987 11.3440 11.7560 11.6500
[7,] 8.4169 8.6875 10.2140 10.0430 11.3640 11.6500 12.7100
  Standard Deviations: 2.9631 3.0778 3.2723 3.1745 3.4778 3.4287 3.5651 
> logLik(d.gls)
'log Lik.' -617.4479 (df=49)
```

lmer function:

```
   > d.lm <- lmer(Strength ~ Program * Timef +(0+Timef|Subj),d,control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
    Warning message:
    In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
      Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00271822 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
    > #VarCorr(d.lm)
    > as.matrix(Matrix::bdiag(VarCorr(d.lm)))
              Timef2   Timef4    Timef6    Timef8   Timef10   Timef12   Timef14
    Timef2  8.534639 8.756711  8.965454  8.198261  8.677920  8.220413  8.416961
    Timef4  8.756711 9.227384  9.462754  8.568308  9.201094  8.730927  8.687653
    Timef6  8.965454 9.462754 10.462654  9.926419 10.665922 10.070205 10.213872
    Timef8  8.198261 8.568308  9.926419  9.832025 10.599504  9.898893 10.043531
    Timef10 8.677920 9.201094 10.665922 10.599504 11.849795 11.344650 11.364012
    Timef12 8.220413 8.730927 10.070205  9.898893 11.344650 11.511176 11.650515
    Timef14 8.416961 8.687653 10.213872 10.043531 11.364012 11.650515 12.465186
    > logLik(d.lm)
    'log Lik.' -617.4479 (df=50)
```

lme function is super slow and fails to converge. My questions are:

1. Considering that gls function does not produce a warning whereas lmer function does, do we trust the gls result rather than lmer result?
2. Are the two models by gls and lmer are the same unstructured model ? If not, why their log likelihood is the same (-617)? If yes, why the variance-covariance estimates are different?
3. Is it possible to reproduce the gls unstructured model using lme/lmer function?

**UPDATE**
I was able to generate the results using `lme()` through a different optimizer "optim":

```
    > d.lme <- lme(Strength ~ Program * Timef, random = ~ -1+Timef | Subj, d,control = lmeControl(maxIter = 50, msMaxIter = 50, msVerbose = TRUE,opt='optim'))
initial  value 1202.821021 
iter  10 value 1202.809062
iter  20 value 1202.789065
final  value 1202.784342 
converged
> #VarCorr(d.lme)
> getVarCov(d.lme)
Random effects variance covariance matrix
        Timef2 Timef4  Timef6  Timef8 Timef10 Timef12 Timef14
Timef2  8.5759 8.7549  8.9628  8.1949  8.6764  8.2180  8.4140
Timef4  8.7549 9.2691  9.4601  8.5649  9.1991  8.7284  8.6841
Timef6  8.9628 9.4601 10.5030  9.9229 10.6630 10.0680 10.2100
Timef8  8.1949 8.5649  9.9229  9.8725 10.5970  9.8965 10.0400
Timef10 8.6764 9.1991 10.6630 10.5970 11.8910 11.3420 11.3600
Timef12 8.2180 8.7284 10.0680  9.8965 11.3420 11.5510 11.6480
Timef14 8.4140 8.6841 10.2100 10.0400 11.3600 11.6480 12.5060
  Standard Deviations: 2.9285 3.0445 3.2408 3.1421 3.4483 3.3987 3.5363 
> logLik(d.lme)
'log Lik.' -617.4481 (df=50)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. There is no `Timef` variable in the data frame (I guess it's the factor recoding of `Time`). You might want to add library information too (I can see them on tags.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed 3 lines to transform the variables to factors. Please let me know if it still does not work. Thanks!

Comment: These seem to be different models. There's a critical error message if you omit the `control` argument to `lmer()`: "Error: number of observations (=399) <= number of random effects (=399) for term (0 + Timef | Subj); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable." Please edit the question to explain in more detail why you think that should be the same model as with `gls`; please don't respond only in a comment, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM, I do not know if these are the same model. If they are not, is it possible to reproduce the results in lmer and lme (Q3) ?

Answer (score 0):

The `gls` and `lme` models have an important difference. As this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1437343/5044791) quotes from [Pinheiro and Bates](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387989570):

> The **gls** function... can be veiwed as an **lme** function without the argument *random*.

Although the matrix of error correlations among observations in your `gls` model has no imposed *internal* structure, it has a very strict structure within the model: except for your allowing different variances within `Timef` groups via the `VarIdent()` you supplied to the `weights` argument, the very same correlation matrix is assumed for all individuals.

The `lme` model that eventually worked for you assumes by default *no* within-individual correlations. It instead models individuals as having random `Timef` *coefficients* that have a strictly normal distribution within each value of `Timef`.

Although in this case the fixed-effect coefficients seem to be the same in the `gls` and `lme` models (as in the linked [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1437343/5044791)), I don't think that you can necessarily expect the "unstructured" error-correlation matrix in `gls` to be *exactly* "reproduced" by the variance-covariance matrix of the sets of `Timef` coefficients that are normally distributed among individuals, although they do come close here. (That might be the case asymptotically in the limit of large numbers of observations.)

Maybe more important is the difference in the ways to think about the models. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486980/28500) emphasizes the marginal (`gls`) versus conditional (`lme`) interpretations, and has a link to why some results reported for `lmer` models aren't the same as for corresponding `lme` models.